# Function within Class accessing 'this'

Tags: typescript

This is a very basic example of the function I'm trying to achieve. My problem is that when calling 'greet', appConfig will not exist on 'this' since it's inside the function.

How can I maintain access to the outer 'this' and be able to call appConfig? I'm hoping to do this without assigning the outer 'this' to some variable like self.

```js
class Greeter {
 
 static $inject = ['appConfig'];
    constructor(
  private appConfig: any
 ) {
    }
 
    greet() {
        return getMessage();
  
  function getMessage() { 
   return this.appConfig.value;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Don't use arrow function, try var self = this in the outer function, because arrow functions has their own specific use case.

Comment: @AliTorabi what's their specific use case?

Comment: Arrow functions are more appropriate for situation a "callback" is required, not encapsulating "functionality"

Comment: @AliTorabi why is that? I think they're appropriate when you want to lexically bind `this`.

Comment: @DavidSherret Of course, as a language feature, but I am more comfortable to put a mental division between callbacks and functionality

Comment: @AliTorabi that sounds more like a coding standard though. I mostly only use arrow methods for callbacks as well and use function declarations for functionality, but in some rare cases I'll use an arrow function for repeated functionality specific to the method that would be overkill to move out of the method. Anyway, it's hard to tell the point of the code in this question is :)

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to avoid the var self = this. Maybe I don't have a good reason too though and should just use it. 
@DavidSherret The arrow function should work, thanks. Yea, the example was super simplified. I've run into the need when I want to wrap up some functionality, or on something recursive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **arrow functions** instead. They inherit the closure's context.

```js
class Greeter {

  static $inject = ['appConfig'];
  constructor(
    private appConfig: any
  ) {}

  greet() {
    let getMessage = () => this.appConfig.value;

    return getMessage();
  }
}
```

You can read more on arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Although in this case I would recommend you just make another private method in the class and call that.

```js
class Greeter {

  static $inject = ['appConfig'];
  constructor(
    private appConfig: any
  ) {}

  greet() {
    return this.getMessage();
  }

  private getMessage() {
    return this.appConfig.value;
  }
}
```